# Selecting a string beginning with $ and ending with $

Tags: texstudio, scripts

The LaTeX editor I use, TeXStudio, allows for custom script-macros. I have little experience with JAVASCRIPT, but I do have one script I managed to create after reading the [TeXstudio : user manual](http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/texstudio/html/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) providing me with a list of JAVASCRIPT commands.

My example (primitive) script using only the commands in the user manual

```
%SCRIPT
txt = cursor.selectedText()
editor.write("{")
ln = cursor.lineNumber()
cn = cursor.columnNumber()
editor.write(txt+"}")
cursor.moveTo(ln,cn);
cursor.movePosition(1,cursorEnums.Left)
```

The above script presupposes the cursor selected some string. Then it surrounds it with "{" "}", and leaves the cursor in the desired location.

I am interested in a similar (inverse) script where the cursor is between $ $, and is able to select everything in between $ and $.

Much like how Ctrl+W selects an entire word, I want to create a script (which will be mapped to some shortcut) that selects an entire math environment between $ and $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script **assumes** (i) your cursor is lying inside the math environment `$..$` already, and that (ii) the whole `$...$` content lies within a single line (this condition can be relaxed, but would make for a more fragile code, I think).

**NOTE**:
It fails (doesn't check for) the following situation:

```
There are $x$ apples| and $y$ oranges.
```

where your cursor sits on `|`, the result is `apples and` being selected. This could be improved upon, but would take a little bit more work. Last I checked, there is no function to 'check if the cursor is within a math environment'.
So one probably needs to count the number of `$` from the beginning of the line, check if the count is even/odd etc.etc. (But even this is not foolproof..)

---

```
%SCRIPT

// grab the line the cursor is on
var ln = cursor.lineNumber();
var tl = editor.text(ln);

// get text before and after cursor
var beforeText = tl.substr(0, cursor.columnNumber());
var afterText = tl.substr(cursor.columnNumber(), tl.length);

// search for last $ before cursor, and first $ after cursor
var op = beforeText.lastIndexOf('\$');
var cl = afterText.indexOf('\$');
if (op>=0 && cl>=0){
    // match found, select everything between the $$
    cursor.selectColumns(op+1, cl+cursor.columnNumber())
}
```

In the gif, I am activating the macro with the default <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> when I'm letting the cursor sit for a while.

[image]

Test case:

```
% Test 1: Standard test
There are $x$ apples and $y$ oranges.
A longer expression might be $ \alpha + \beta = \gamma $

% Test 2: $$ across lines (fails) -- condition can be relaxed
$
x + y = \sqrt{2}
$
```

---

Comment: I noticed (and expected) that you used commands not listed in the usermanual. Do you have a recommended beginnner / intermediate / advanced reference for learning what commands are predefined? I am quite amazed by the gif you posted.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase Only `cursor.selectColumns()` is not listed in the user manual. The rest are either [ecmascript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ecmascript.html) standard functions (string manipulation) or already present in the user manual. As for reference, I don't have one, sorry. (read the source code of Texstudio?)